# Grails HasMany List Relation to Extended Class having BelongsTo Relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am having a problem setting up a List as a hasMany relationship to a belongsTo withing an extended class.

With a new Grails 2.4.4 app I have these 3 Domains:

An Author class having many books.

```
class Author {
    List books
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}
```

A Book class which extends Content

```
class Book extends Content {
    String foo
}
```

And Content, which has a number of common properties.

```
class Content {
    String title
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
    static constraints = {
        sort: 'title'
    }
}
```

When running this application I get the following exception:

*Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: test.relationships.Book column: author_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")*

I only get this exception when I make books a List.

Comment: Do you need to define `books` as a list?  I think it's treated as a list by default from the `hasMany` notation such that you don't need to define it as a separate variable.  Hence your "repeated column."  Just a guess.

Comment: Actually by default, `books` would be a set. I think specifying the type like this is the correct way to ensure that the `books` collection is mapped as a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is probably something to do with the fact you're saying that `Author` has many `Book`s, but the superclass of `Book`, `Content`, belongs to an `Authur`.

What happens if you change your `Content` and `Book` classes to this:

```
class Content {
    String title
    static constraints = {
        sort: 'title'
    }
}

class Book extends Content {
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
    String foo
}
```

or, alternatively, change your `Author` class to this:

```
class Author {
    List books
    static hasMany = [contents: Content]
}
```

Comment: This would defeat the purpose of the relationship being on the parent class.
If I have 20 different classes that are a child of Content, then I will need to specify the relationship of every child. 

Your solution simply takes away the fact im using extends.  

And to change Author to reference contents in its hasMany would return all children even those that are not Books (say if the same author has some Albums)

The problem is I know every Content has an Author, but I want to only get lists of certain types of Content.